# Can iframe access its own localStorage when block third-party cookies?

Tags: javascript, iframe

We are trying to insert an iframe in another domain, but when third-party cookies are disabled, this error occurs:

> "Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document";

But we don't want to access parent `localStorage`. Is there any way to access the iframe's own `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

Under Chrome's Settings > Privacy > Content settings, you have the cookie setting set to to "Block 3rd party cookies"

You will have to uncheck this box.